# Social (Google & Facebook) buttons don't align in a horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, facebook, button, android-linearlayout, google-signin

So as the title says; I am having issues with aligning my social login buttons within a horizontal LinearLayout. I have tried this with normal buttons and they align perfectly, but whenever I switch back to the Facebook and Google buttons they misalign for some reason.

This is what they look like in design view:

[image]

And this is my XML code:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />


            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/googleButton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting android:layout_gravity="center" in your LinearLayout.

Comment: Maybe just android:gravity="center" ?

Comment: Yes, actually a very silly mistake. All I had to do was change android:layout_gravity="centre_horizontally" to ="center" - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />


    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/googleButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```